# Crash when i try to play a sound as loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to play a sound as loop. It starts playing fine, but when the sound ends, and it should started to play again, the program crashes.

this is my code:

```
private void audio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    playAudio();
}

private void playAudio()
{
    SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.music);
    audio.PlayLooping();
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Error message would help us to help you... code inside PlayLooping would help too

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler PlayLooping() belongs to the SoundPlayer, which is from System.Media. Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Regardless, it's might be better to create *one* SoundPlayer and re-use it. There [is an example here, pretty much showing the posted code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-loop-a-sound-playing-on-a-windows-form) with the changes to use a single sound player. As PlayLooping() creates a new thread, it's probably better to ensure the previous source is stopped; or to use the same instance so the same resources will be used unless overlap is actually desired..

Comment: Thank-you, can you get the error details to us too? It would be easier to get sense of the problem and possibly a solution...

Comment: It is probably getting garbage collected.

Comment: Define the Player (class scope) as `SoundPlayer audio;` then initialize it in your playAudio() method: `audio = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.music);`. It has to be assumed that the .wav file is not currupted.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response.
user2864740 that was my problem.

i changed it now so that i have only one SoundPlayer and it works perfect now:

```
SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.music);
private void audio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    audio.PlayLooping();
}
```